# Inline editing and saving to database takes very long time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to make an editable table and directly save it to a database.
I use code from:

```html
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js
```

Here is the JavaScript function:

```js
<script>
function showEdit(editableObj) {
    $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF");
} 

function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
    $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
    $.ajax({
        url: "saveedit.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
        success: function(data){
            $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
        }        
   });
}
</script>
```

And this is the code to save it:

```html
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE php_interview_questions set " . $_POST["column"] . " = '".$_POST["editval"]."' WHERE  id=".$_POST["id"]);
?>
```

And this is the example of how I put it into PHP:

```html
<tr class="table-row">
    <td><?php echo $k+1; ?></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["question"]; ?></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'answer','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["answer"]; ?></td>
</tr>
```

When I run the file, it takes a very long time to load and save it. How can I tune this?

Comment: May you share code of `dbcontroller.php` or class `DBController` code ;)

Comment: ...
 function __construct() {
  $conn = $this->connectDB();
  if(!empty($conn)) {
   $this->selectDB($conn);}}
 function connectDB() {
  $conn = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password);
  return $conn;}
 function selectDB($conn) {
  mysql_select_db($this->database,$conn);}
 function runQuery($query) {
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $resultset[] = $row;}  
  if(!empty($resultset))
   return $resultset;}
 function numRows($query) {
  $result  = mysql_query($query);
  $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
  return $rowcount; }}

Answer (score 0):

Hello why you not download this file `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js` in your local machine and use this

Comment: i have downloaded it and save it to my local machine

Comment: still this problem